# Input Onclick button Function

Tags: javascript, php, html, function

Hello Guys I have a textbox which if the value inside the textbox is zero. It will pop up alert. but no alert is happening.

```
<input type="text" id="numbers" value= "0" >



                  <th style="width:5%;"><h4><input id="submitbutton" onclick="clicked();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="<?php if($final==true){ echo "viewsummary" ;}else{ echo "next";} ?>" value="<?php if($final==true){ echo "View Summary" ;}else{ echo "Submit";} ?>" class="subbtn"/>

                    <script language="javascript">

                    document.getElementById('submitbutton')
                    function clicked(){
                        if (document.getElementById('numbers') == 0) {
                        window.alert("Please Play the Audio First");
                    }

                    }                        
                    </script>
```

I dont know whats the error If I look at the code for me its just fine? whats wrong? Thank you guys :")

Comment: You might be encountering script error, look at this line which is not terminated properly or not written correctly. document.getElementById('submitbutton')

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function clicked()
{
   if (document.getElementById('numbers') && document.getElementById('numbers').value == 0)
   {
     window.alert("Please Play the Audio First");
   }
}
```

Comment: @Nathaniel, if it works for you, mark it as the accepted answer so someone else facing similar problem can benefit from it.

Comment: Yes sir u just wait 5 min

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the value, not the element:

```
document.getElementById('numbers').value == "0"
```

Also, `value` will be a string and not a number. Full code:

```
//document.getElementById('submitbutton')
//^^ this does nothing

function clicked() {
    if (document.getElementById('numbers').value === "0") {
        window.alert("Please Play the Audio First");
    }

}
```

Don't forget, inside a `form` this may trigger the form action. `"Please Play the Audio First"` indicates that you don't want the form to submit if that `if` statement is hit, so you should return a value to stop that happening:

```
function clicked() {
    if (document.getElementById('numbers').value === "0") {
        window.alert("Please Play the Audio First");
    }
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="submitbutton" onclick="return clicked();" .... />
```

Comment: Its still not working sir huhuhu no alert happens :(

Comment: Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/sdzg2hr0/ - You'd need to see why yours differs from this working version